# How do I use passport.js to GET JSON using accessToken of an already logged in user?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, discord, discord.js

I'm able to do a GET request to grab JSON from discord while using the access token that's supplied by passport. How can I use passport to grab the accessToken of a logged in user to do GET requests on another page?

```
passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: keys.discord.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.discord.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/discord/redirect'
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    request({
        url: 'https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds',
        auth: {
            'bearer': accessToken
        }
    }, (err, res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
    });

    User.findOne({ discordId: profile.id }).then((currentUser) => {
        if (currentUser) {
            done(null, currentUser);
        } else {
            new User({
                discordId: profile.id
            }).save().then((newUser) => {
                console.log('Created new user: ', newUser);
                done(null, newUser);
            });
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: You should save the access token after successfull login in the local storage and use it later when you would like. Do not forget to delete it too from local storage when logout.

Comment: Have a look at JWT tokens. You can create a JWT token from the user ID and client secret. Then send the token in each request to authenticate the client. Let me know if this is suitable solution and I can give you an example.

Comment: @SvetoslavPetrov That sounds like a great solution. Could you show me an example please? I was unaware storing the token in local storage was even an option.

Answer (score 1):

So I will skip the passport part and will show you the token exchange:

The signin method:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
[...]
app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('signin'), (req, res) => {
    if (req.user){
        // Set the JWT token for this session
        const token = jwt.sign(
            { id: req.user.id }, 
            keys.discord.clientSecret, 
            { expiresIn: config.SESSION_DURATION } //The validity time (optional)
        );

        const currentDate = new Date();
        return res.status(200).send({
            auth: true, 
            token: token,
            // These two properties below are optional if you want to keep track
            // of the session duration and send some more user info
            tokenDuration: { 
                expire: currentDate.setMilliseconds(currentDate.getMilliseconds() + config.SESSION_DURATION)},

            user: {firstname: req.user.firstname, lastname: req.user.lastname}
        });
    }

    return res.status(401).send('Could not login');
});
```

Then when you make requests from the client:

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${url}/path`,
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'x-access-token': jwtToken, // This is the "token" property from above
    },
    json: true
})
```

And finally you handle the above request in the server:

```
app.post('/path', (req, res) => {
    jwt.verify(req.headers['x-access-token'], keys.discord.clientSecret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            // The user is not authorized, handle properly
        }

        // User is authorized, do stuff
});
```

Hopefully this will be enough for you to start. Like I mentioned have a look at JWT, their documentation is well written :)